# How to find a reference to an array by the name of the variable as defined in the code in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, variable-names

Obviously, I'm not looking for the classic:

```
string[] garden = {"Tulip"};
Console.WriteLine(garden[0]);
```

but rather, doing the same with a string:

```
string[] garden = {"Tulip"};
string gardenname = "garden";
string[] cool_NEW_array = ArrayByName(gardenname);
Console.WriteLine(cool_NEW_array[0])
```

I'm curious as to whether there is some actually existing version of "ArrayByName" which would let me find an array by using a string which is its name. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `garden` is an object reference, not a name.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: You can create an method and use c# reflection to get property details. If it is a property and then type cast it to an array and access properties

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp so... there's no way (you know of) to do this?

Comment: as @KyleWang said something like `Dictionary<string, object>()` or `Dictionary<string, dynamic>()` but it's not going to be a `cool_NEW` it would be the same (reference)

Comment: so you want to lookup objects based on keys? because garden is just a reference.

Comment: @KyleWang honestly, i'm starting to believe so! lists are more versatile, but come with some complications, and arrays are very basic, so you're... right? (i guess)

Comment: @OlivierRogier it is, just not with arrays from what i've heard

Comment: your best bet would be a `Dictionary` with an object for a value or a `KeyValuePair` in the same way

Comment: @HMZ yes yes, i'm trying to learn the usage of those "dictionaries" currently. it is by far the best bet. still, i hate how lists and dictionaries force you to add items one-by-one.

Comment: You can add more than one thing to a list at a time... `AddRange` takes an enumerable.. this sounds like an X/Y question to be honest. You are asking how to do something that you think solves a problem instead of showing what problem you are trying to solve and letting people give you the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible, as I know, and this may cause lots of problems about reflexion and generated IL.

There is the `nameof` operator and meanings to get variables names in the caller of a method, but it is not intended for your goal.

Perhaps there some reflection tools to do that, but I don't know.

Perhaps you can do that using huge reflexion on a whole assembly by parsing all classes, all instances, all fields and properties members, all methods and all local vars of these methods...

In all case, you may encounter problems with duplicates vocabulary.

But you can use a `Dictionary` keyed by the name of the intended variable name.

Thus you create a sort of data table.

We use a class variable as private to store some one-dimension string arrays and public methods to add and remove these arrays from the collection as well as a method to find which can match having one string using Contains (or equality if you want).

**The collection**

```cs
static private readonly Dictionary<string, string[]> RegisteredArrays 
  = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
```

**The register and unbregister methods**

```cs
static public void RegisterArray(string name, string[] array)
{
  if ( !RegisteredArrays.ContainsKey(name)
    && !RegisteredArrays.ContainsValue(array) )
    RegisteredArrays.Add(name, array);
}

static public void UnregisterArray(string name)
{
  if ( RegisteredArrays.ContainsKey(name) )
    RegisteredArrays.Remove(name);
}

static public void UnregisterArray(string[] array)
{
  if ( RegisteredArrays.ContainsValue(array) )
  {
    var item = RegisteredArrays.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value == array).Key;
    RegisteredArrays.Remove(item);
  }
}
```

**The find method**

```cs
static public IEnumerable<string[]> FindRegisteredArray(string name)
{
  foreach ( var item in RegisteredArrays )
    if ( item.Key == name )
      yield return item.Value;
}
```

**Test**

```cs
static void Test()
{
  string[] garden1 = { "Tulip", "Rose" };
  string[] garden2 = { "Flower 1", "Flower 2", "Flower 3" };

  RegisterArray(nameof(garden1), garden1);
  RegisterArray(nameof(garden2), garden2);

  string gardenname = "garden1";

  foreach ( var array in FindRegisteredArray(gardenname) )
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array));

  foreach ( var array in FindRegisteredArray("garden2") )
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array));
}
```

**Output**

```html
Tulip,Rose
Flower 1,Flower 2,Flower 3
```

**Improvements**

*You can create a whole class to offer the desired behavior*

```cs
static public class NamedStringArrayManager
{
  static private readonly Dictionary<string, string[]> RegisteredArrays
    = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

  static public void Register(string name, string[] array)
  {
    if ( !RegisteredArrays.ContainsKey(name)
      && !RegisteredArrays.ContainsValue(array) )
      RegisteredArrays.Add(name, array);
  }

  static public void Unregister(string name)
  {
    if ( RegisteredArrays.ContainsKey(name) )
      RegisteredArrays.Remove(name);
  }

  static public void Unregister(string[] array)
  {
    if ( RegisteredArrays.ContainsValue(array) )
    {
      var item = RegisteredArrays.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value == array).Key;
      RegisteredArrays.Remove(item);
    }
  }

  static public IEnumerable<string[]> Find(string name)
  {
    foreach ( var item in RegisteredArrays )
      if ( item.Key == name )
        yield return item.Value;
  }
}
```

```cs
static void Test()
{
  string[] garden1 = { "Tulip", "Rose" };
  string[] garden2 = { "Flower 1", "Flower 2", "Flower 3" };

  NamedStringArrayManager.Register(nameof(garden1), garden1);
  NamedStringArrayManager.Register(nameof(garden2), garden2);

  string gardenname = "garden1";

  foreach ( var array in NamedStringArrayManager.Find(gardenname) )
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array));

  foreach ( var array in NamedStringArrayManager.Find("garden2") )
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array));
}
```

*We can also create a generic manager for any type*

```
static public class NamedInstanceManager<T>
{
  static private readonly Dictionary<string, T> RegisteredArrays
    = new Dictionary<string, T>();

  static public void Register(string name, T instance)
  {
    if ( !RegisteredArrays.ContainsKey(name)
      && !RegisteredArrays.ContainsValue(instance) )
      RegisteredArrays.Add(name, instance);
  }

  static public void Unregister(string name)
  {
    if ( RegisteredArrays.ContainsKey(name) )
      RegisteredArrays.Remove(name);
  }

  static public void Unregister(T instance)
  {
    if ( RegisteredArrays.ContainsValue(instance) )
    {
      var item = RegisteredArrays.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value.Equals(instance)).Key;
      RegisteredArrays.Remove(item);
    }
  }

  static public IEnumerable<T> Find(string name)
  {
    foreach ( var item in RegisteredArrays )
      if ( item.Key == name )
        yield return item.Value;
  }
}
```

Or simply any object:

```
static public class NamedInstanceManager
{
  static private readonly Dictionary<string, object> RegisteredArrays
    = new Dictionary<string, object>();

  static public void Register(string name, object instance)
  {
    if ( !RegisteredArrays.ContainsKey(name)
      && !RegisteredArrays.ContainsValue(instance) )
      RegisteredArrays.Add(name, instance);
  }

  static public void Unregister(string name)
  {
    if ( RegisteredArrays.ContainsKey(name) )
      RegisteredArrays.Remove(name);
  }

  static public void Unregister(object instance)
  {
    if ( RegisteredArrays.ContainsValue(instance) )
    {
      var item = RegisteredArrays.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value.Equals(instance)).Key;
      RegisteredArrays.Remove(item);
    }
  }

  static public IEnumerable<object> Find(string name)
  {
    foreach ( var item in RegisteredArrays )
      if ( item.Key == name )
        yield return item.Value;
  }
}
```

Also we can manage registering and unregistering several differents names for the same reference and so on... by throwing an exception, returning a bool or do nothing.

Here the code only accept to add a name or a reference only if both is not already in the collection.